# How to prevent circular dependency between SwiftUI TextField's onChange?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm working on a SwiftUI view that contains two TextFields, one for amount and another for percentage. Both TextFields are bound to their respective @State variables using the $ symbol.

```
struct ContentView2: View {
    @State private var amount: String = ""
    @State private var percentage: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("enter value here", text: $amount)
            TextField("enter percentage here", text: $percentage)
            
                .onChange(of: amount, perform: onAmountChange(_:))
                .onChange(of: percentage, perform: onPercentageChange(_:))
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func onAmountChange(_ newValue: String) {
        // while setting percentage, `percentage` is a state property that triggers onPercentageChange(_:)
        percentage = newValue
        // Is there a way to stop triggering the onPercentageChange(_:) method here?
    }
    
    func onPercentageChange(_ newValue: String) {
        // while setting amount, `amount` is a state property that triggers onAmountChange(_:)
        amount = newValue
        // Is there a way to stop triggering the onAmountChange(_:) method here?
    }
}
```

Issue:

The problem I'm facing is that when I update the amount, it triggers the onAmountChange(*:) method, which sets the percentage. However, setting the percentage also triggers the onPercentageChange(*:) method, creating a circular dependency

Question:

Is there a way to prevent this circular dependency and avoid the onAmountChange(_:) method from triggering when setting percentage, and vice versa? I want to update the values of amount and percentage without calling second function. Any guidance or alternative approaches would be highly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What is the purpose to set the values crosswise? This causes the infinite loop.

Comment: Why do you need it? Have you tried format or formatter?

Comment: You could use @FocusState to keep track of which field changed

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Setting amount triggers both `onPercentageChange` and `onAmountChange` as expected and _once_ - because although you setting percent from amount and vice versa, unless they change yet again in that circle, second time event won't trigger. So please provide a reproducible issue

Answer (score 1):

One way approach the problem and avoid the circular dependency is to use a "Model" where you execute the logic, and use the view solely to render state and send user interactions.

The solution below is close to the MVI pattern (Model View Intent) which is basically a unidirectional and event driven approach. In this pattern, the view is strictly a function of state and the logic is performed elsewhere, namely in the "Model". By the way, it does not only solve the circular dependency, but also offers a few more very much desired principles which makes your code testable, reliable and comprehensible.

SwiftUI is perfect to implement it, we just need to figure out the bindings. See below:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

// User Interactions
enum Intent {
    case amount(String)
    case percentage(String)
}

// The state of the view
struct ViewState {
    var amount: String = ""
    var percentage: String = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        let amountBinding = Binding(
            get: { model.viewState.amount },
            set: { value in model.send(.amount(value)) }
        )
        
        let percentageBinding = Binding(
            get: { model.viewState.percentage },
            set: { value in model.send(.percentage(value)) }
        )

        VStack {
            TextField("enter value here", text: amountBinding)
            TextField("enter percentage here", text: percentageBinding)
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
}


@MainActor
final class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var viewState: ViewState = .init()
    
    
    func send(_ intent: Intent) {
        self.viewState = Model.update(self.viewState, intent: intent)
    }

    // This function performs the whole logic of your view. It's only 
    // taking the current state and an intent that happened and computes
    // a new state.
    static func update(_ state: ViewState, intent: Intent) -> ViewState {
        switch intent {
        case .amount(let value):
            guard let x = Double(value) else {
                return .init(amount: value, percentage: "")
            }
            return .init(amount: value, percentage: "\(x * 100)")
        
        case .percentage(let value):
            guard let x = Double(value) else {
                return .init(amount: "", percentage: value)
            }
            return .init(amount: "\(x / 100)", percentage: value)
        
        } 
    }

}
```

What's important to note here, is that the whole logic will be performed in *one* function and that this function is *pure* and thus, can be easily tested.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually set the new value on text changes in SwiftUI's TextField. The TextField view uses the provided binding as a two-way binding, allowing it to read and write data automatically.

Simply remove the two onChange modifiers, and the TextField will work as expected without any additional configuration.

For more information and a detailed explanation on two-way bindings in SwiftUI, you can refer to the following resource: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/two-way-bindings-in-swiftui

Comment: thanks for answer but i need to do custom calculation when value changes in one textField that's why i'm using onChange modifier

Answer (score 0):

Used @FocusState modifier to keep track which textField is focused

if i'm writing in TextField1 that'll be focused in calculate(percentage
method check if TextField1 is focused if it's then return else continue
same will go for TextField 2

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @FocusState private var isTextField1Focused: Bool
    @FocusState private var isTextField2Focused: Bool

    @State private var textField1Text: String = ""
    @State private var textField2Text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("TextField 1", text: $textField1Text)
                .focused($isTextField1Focused)

            TextField("TextField 2", text: $textField2Text)
                .focused($isTextField2Focused)
        }
        .padding()
        .onChange(of: textField1Text, perform: calculate(cost:))
        .onChange(of: textField2Text, perform: calculate(percentage:))
    }
    
    func calculate(cost: String) {
        // here calcuate percentage
        guard !isTextField2Focused else { return }
        textField2Text = cost
        
    }
   
    func calculate(percentage: String) {
        // here calcuate percentage
        guard !isTextField1Focused else { return }
        textField1Text = percentage
    }
}
```